# Jetty resource base directory filtering

Tags: configuration, jetty

I have a jetty project (running through the gradle jetty plugin but I don't think that's important here). I have configured the resource base to point to some directory X. That directory has a bunch of subdirectories, A, B and C. When I go to the root page `http://mywebserver/X`, it shows directories A,B and C as expected.

Is there a way to filter out certain directories, so it shows only A and B for example (and C is inaccessible). I know I could setup different web contexts for each one, but I'd prefer to be able to add the top level directory and then filter out the directories I do or do not want.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml file for your webapp, you can set a security constraint.  For each directory you want to restrict, you can set the URL pattern and the types of http method you want to restrict from being performed.

Since the XML can get fairly complicated and you have a specific use case, [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security) is a good article that explains how to set up the security constraint in your web.xml file.  Keep in mind that any http methods that you do not explicitly list in your security constraint are automatically allowed.  I hope this answer has helped!

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll check this out. I'll be back to upvote and accept if it works.

Comment: While it looks like the security part did work, it doesn't seem to restrict listing the directories using gradle's embedded jetty. This still might be right track, though not sure yet.